# Print path for bellman ford

Tags: python, bellman-ford

My task is the following. I have a **start vertex, an end vertex**. I need to find the **shortest path between those 2.**
In my code, I was able to find the shortest path cost, but I don't understand how to return the path corresponding to that cost.

Input is a graph in the following form [[vertex_from,vertex_to,cost],[vertex_from,vertex_to,cost]...]

```
def belmanford(adj_matrix, v_from, v_to):
n, graph = len(graphe(adj_matrix)), adj_matrix

dist = [float("inf") for i in range(n)] # all vertices are considered not visited
dist[v_from]=0#cost from start vertex to end vertex is null

for i in range(1,n):
    for u,v,c in graph:#iterating over all vertices
        
       
                
                
                if dist[u] != float("inf") and dist[u] +c < dist[v]:  
                        dist[v] = dist[u] + c #we have in dist all distances from vertex start to another one and we replace them when we find a better one
  
if dist[v_to]!=float("inf"):

    return dist[v_to]#shortest path
else:
    return -1
```

Examples of test cases:

```
adj_matrix =[[0, 1, 5], [0, 2, 2], [1, 0, 5], [2, 0, 2]]
result=[0,2]
```

Comment: Are you actually using a graph library? Have a look at e.g. networkx. Don't spend time redeveloping stuff that already exists.

Comment: Unless this is for learning, of course.

Comment: It's for my college class indeed. Q1 is to find the shortest path (the code that I put previously and it works) and then Q2 is to send the path. But I don't know how to get this path. I believe we need to store each parent vertice somewhere, but I don't know to actually code it.

Comment: Bellman-ford can work with negative weights, returning -1 can cause problem